# Does IND-CPA imply PRF?

Tags: pseudo-random-function, chosen-plaintext-attack

It is well-known that a pseudorandom function (PRF) can be used to build a CPA-secure symmetric cryptosystem. My question: is PRF necessary for this, i.e., can one show something like "If there exists an IND-CPA scheme then there exist PRF?"

Comment: Thank you Geoffroy, that is very helpful (& a complete answer!) --m

Comment: Happy to help :) If you got the answer you were looking for, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there exists an IND-CPA symmetric encryption scheme (where the key is shorter than the total length of the messages, i.e., the scheme is not the OTP), then [there are one-way functions](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/techreports/tr-89-31). A sequence of articles have shown how to construct pseudorandom generators out of OWFs (culminating with [this paper](https://www.nada.kth.se/~johanh/prgfromowf.pdf)). By the [GGM construction](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/shafi/1986-jacm.pdf), pseudorandom generators can be used to construct PRFs. Therefore, IND-CPA symmetric encryption implies PRFs.

Comment: Can you please link to relevant papers?

Comment: As soon as my internet connection allows me to open pdfs, yes

Comment: http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/pubs/techreports/tr-89-31 ​ http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/shafi/1986-jacm.pdf $\hspace{.4 in}$

Comment: Thanks, finally got a correct connection (was in the train), I added references.